# MonoTouch DialogViewController is Empty Until Touched

Tags: xamarin.ios, monotouch.dialog

I have a `TabBarController` app with a `DialogViewController` that works fine except that on initial load the table is EMPTY until I touch it or navigate to another tab and back (http://cl.ly/3I0r1v2b420t0L1X1h2w).

I have confirmed the `Root` is set. I've tried issuing a `ReloadData()` after. I've also tried setting the `TableView.Source` directly. In every case the `TableView` doesn't show anything until another action occurs.

This happens in the simulator and on the iPhone.

Any idea why this might be?

```
public partial class PapersView : DialogViewController
{
    public PapersView () : base (UITableViewStyle.Plain, null, true)
    {
        EnableSearch = true; 
        AutoHideSearch = true;
        SearchPlaceholder = @"Find Papers";
    }

    public override void ViewDidLoad ()
    {
        base.ViewDidLoad ();

        MonoTouch.UIKit.UIApplication.SharedApplication.NetworkActivityIndicatorVisible = true;
        var svc = new PaperService ();
        svc.GetPapers (onPapersReceived, onErrorReceived);
    }

    private void onErrorReceived (string error)
    {
        MonoTouch.UIKit.UIApplication.SharedApplication.NetworkActivityIndicatorVisible = false;
    }

    private void onPapersReceived (List<PaperNode> papers)
    {
        MonoTouch.UIKit.UIApplication.SharedApplication.NetworkActivityIndicatorVisible = false;

        Root = new RootElement ("Papers") {
                from node in papers
                    group node by (node.paper.title [0].ToString ().ToUpper ()) into alpha
                    orderby alpha.Key
                select new Section (alpha.Key){
                    from eachNode in alpha
                    select (Element)new WhitePaperBible.iOS.UI.CustomElements.PaperElement (eachNode)
        }};

        TableView.ScrollToRow (NSIndexPath.FromRowSection (0, 0), UITableViewScrollPosition.Top, false);
    }
}
```

Comment: What events are being called (or not) on the initial load vs the 2nd load?

Comment: If I understand what you're asking... I set breakpoints in all of the methods and these are only called once when the app initializes. I then touch the UITableView and the data displays as I scroll. Same result if I hit another tab and come back...nothing else is called in that DialogViewController but the data shows up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Curtis Bailey pointed me on the MonoTouch mailing list to look at InvokeOnMainThread. That solved this issue because the asynchronous service call is on a background thread and so too was the callback.

```
    private void onPapersReceived (List<PaperNode> papers)
    {
        MonoTouch.UIKit.UIApplication.SharedApplication.NetworkActivityIndicatorVisible = false;

        InvokeOnMainThread (delegate {
            Root = new RootElement("Papers") {
                    from node in papers
                        group node by (node.paper.title [0].ToString ().ToUpper ()) into alpha
                        orderby alpha.Key
                    select new Section (alpha.Key){
                        from eachNode in alpha
                        select (Element)new WhitePaperBible.iOS.UI.CustomElements.PaperElement (eachNode)
            }};

            TableView.ScrollToRow (NSIndexPath.FromRowSection (0, 0), UITableViewScrollPosition.Top, false);
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try just populating the existing Root instead of creating a new Root.

If you look in MonoTouch.Dialog sources for DialogViewController, you should find the PrepareRoot() method. Look to see where that is called and it should start to make sense.